# awk - Print last column value with default value if null

Tags: unix, awk

I am using awk command to print the values. For the last column, if no value is found, I need it to print `NA`.

Ex., in the below code, when `$3` is `NULL`, I need to print as `NA`.

Is there anyway I could include a `if`/`isnull` condition or something.

```
awk -F"    " '{ print $1,"|", $2, "|", $3 }' log_temp.txt > log_template.txt
```

Comment: may be this you are want `awk 'NF<3{$3="NA"}1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway i could include a 'if'/'isnull' condition or something.

You need to use [**ternary operator**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#AWK)

***Syntax:***

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

**For 3rd column**

```
awk '{ print ($3==""?"NA":$3) }' infile
```

**so it becomes**

```
awk '{ print $1, "|" , $2, "|",  ($3==""?"NA":$3) }' infile
```

**You can also set output field separator variable (`OFS`)**

```
awk -v OFS='|' '{ print $1, $2, ($3=="" ? "NA" : $3) }' infile
```

`print ($3=="" ? "NA" : $3)` is same as

```
if( $3=="" ){
    print "NA"
}else{
    print $3
}
```

> For last column you can use `NF` variable which gives no of fields in
>   record, whereas `$NF` is last column

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's exactly what i wanted. A question: Is there anyway I could dynamically get the column count instead of hard coding as print $1, $2 , $3 etc,.

Comment: variable `NF` gives no of fields in record, suppose you want to check all fields then you can just, loop it like `awk -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)if($i=="")$i="NA"; $1=$1}1' infile`, if null then set `NA`, `$1=$1` is used incase if none of the fields are null, but still you can to use output field separator as `|`, then it modifies field separator in record, and `1` at the end does printing of record

Comment: awk -F"    " -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)if($i=="")$i="NA"}1' log_temp.txt > log_template.txt...............................................................................................THANK YOU. I tried this. But I'm not getting the expected output delimited with '|' as i got before. I am just getting whatever was there in the input.

Comment: awk use single space as default field separator so no need to use `-F" "`, to understand how above one works, you may try this : `echo '1,,3' | awk -F, -v OFS='|' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)if($i=="")$i="NA"; $1=$1}1'` would output `1|NA|3`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How you do format in comment section? My code actually has 4 'spaces' as delimiter. it got formatted when i copy pasted in comment box. So from input file, the delimiter is '4 spaces' and when i write it to output i need to delimit with ' | '.  It works perfectly when i hard code print $1 , $2 etc.,. But when i try using 'NF' function, without using print, it's not giving the desired output. Sorry I am new to Unix scripting, I am doing this as part of a challenge event that i am participating.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, awk calculates no of fields based of delimiter, probably in your case no of fields are not consistent, so if you already know how many fields are there in your file, you may use directly replace NF with your number like `for(i=1; i<=10; i++)`

Comment: Yes. No of fields vary among lines. So can the above approach can be applied only if the no.of fields is constant among lines?

Comment: And thank you @akshay. It's because of kind people like you, the internet is such a wonderful place :)

Comment: Yes since you got space separated columns awk will have difficulties to predict fields when null fields encounter, I hope you got my point.

Comment: Just be aware that `print $3==""?"NA":$3`, etc. will produce a syntax error in some awks. Always parenthesise your ternary expressions, e.g. `print ($3==""?"NA":$3)` as even in awks where that's not necessary it improves clarity.

Comment: @EdMorton added parentheses as you suggested, thank you.

Comment: Great. One example of an awk that'd produce a syntax error without them given that code is OSX awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed for this task.

If the delimiter is '4 spaces' in the input file.

You can set a var with the number of fields

```
field=3
# set the number of fields
sed '
s/\([^ ][^ ]*\)/&/'"$field"'
# match each field and operate the substitution on the last field
t
# if the last field is not empty jump to end
s/$/    NA/
# substitute the end of line with delimiter (4 spaces) and NA
' infile

cat infile 
aaaa    bbbb    cccc
dddd    eeee
ffff    gggg    hhhh
iiii    jjjj

output
aaaa    bbbb    cccc
dddd    eeee    NA
ffff    gggg    hhhh
iiii    jjjj    NA
```