# Populate a value in a particular column in csv

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a folder where there are 50 excel sheets in CSV format. I have to populate a  particular value say "XYZ" in the column I of all the sheets in that folder.

I am new to unix and have looked for a couple of pages [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249763/how-to-edit-a-particular-column-in-csv-file-with-unix-command) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444988/sed-editing-specific-column-and-row-in-a-csv-file?rq=1) . Can anyone please provide me the sample script to begin with?

For example :
Let's say column C in this case:

```
A             B        C
ASFD         2535
BDFG         64486
DFGC         336846
```

I want to update column C to value "XYZ".

Thanks.

Comment: @oguzismail Added the same.

Comment: If this is a tab separated file `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR>1{$3="XYZ"} 1' file.tsv` should work.

Comment: Similar question: [awk - Print last column value with default value if null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770452/awk-print-last-column-value-with-default-value-if-null)

Comment: @oguzismail is not a loop required in this as there are 50 such excel sheets and i have to do the same for all.

Comment: Yeah, a for loop will do it.

Comment: @user3901666 a loop isn't required if you do `awk -i inplace 'script' *.csv` with GNU awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would export those files into csv format 
 - with semikolon as field separator
 - eventually by leaving out column descriptions (otherwise see comment below)

Then the following combination of SHELL and SED script could more or less do already the trick

```
#! /bin/sh

for i in *.csv
do
        sed -i -e "s/$/;XZY/" $i
done
```

- -i means to edit the file in place, here you could append the value to all lines
- -e specifies the regular expresssion for substitution

You might want to use a similar script like this, to rename "XYZ" to "C" only in the 1st line if the csv files should contain also column descriptions.